# Snowflake UDTF with dynamic where clause as an argument

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create an UDTF where I am planning to pass the dynamic where clause as an argument to the UDTF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNCTION_NAME(where_clause VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$ var sql_command=SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_1 JOIN TABLE_2 ON .... 
+where_clause+ GROUP BY ...;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} ); 
var resultSet = stmt.execute(); resultSet.next();
$$
```

Is this something possible and also I want to be able to handle quotes in the arguments during calling of the function

for example if the call is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FUNCTION_NAME('WHERE COL_1='value''));
```

How do I handle quotes during calling of the function. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Note that `snowflake.createStatement` is available to JS stored procedures, but not to JS UDFs. So this would not work, regardless of quotes.

Comment: you are aware that this way is perfect for SQL injection

maybe use json with key=value pairs and handle escaping that way.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to underline the answer of Felipe. JavaScript UDTFs do not support "Stored Procedures API".

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html

So you can not create and run a dynamic SQL inside of a JavaScript UDTF. It must have "processRow" callback function to process the values coming as parameters and return them as rows.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html#basic-hello-world-examples

You can create a stored procedure to run a dynamic SQL and return the result as an array/json, but it won't be effective.

For your original question, you just need to escape the quote by repeating it or using slash:

```
call FUNCTION_NAME('WHERE i=''1''');
call FUNCTION_NAME('WHERE i=\'1\'');
```

Comment: tried to call the function using backslash before but it didn't work